# how to make one object point to another using python instead of aimconstraint or pointconstrain?

Tags: python, maya

i want to make an for exemple, cube1 "look" or "point" to sphere1 without using Aim or Point constraint, only using python or pymel, is this possible? thanks :)

i'v try to copy the position in the world but nothing really worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.